# extract a substring from the end of a string until the First space is encountered?

Tags: java, android, substring, space

I have a string like this:

```
"De Proost Wim"
```

And i need `"De Proost"` in a string and `"Wim"` in another

so i need the first `' '` starting at the end of a string.

Comment: You can use `lastIndexOf(' ')` with the `substring` method.

Comment: I hope you're not assuming that people's first names don't contain spaces.  That would be a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`lastIndexOf(' ')`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) with the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method :

```
String s = "De Proost Wim";
int lastIndex = s.lastIndexOf(' ');
String s1 = s.substring(0, lastIndex);
String s2 = s.substring(lastIndex+1);

System.out.println(s1); //De Proost
System.out.println(s2); //Wim
```

Just make sure that `lastIndexOf` doesn't return -1.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = /*Your-String*/;
String[] subs = str.split(" ");
String strLast = "";
if( subs.length > 1 )
    strLast = subs[subs.length-1];
```

Comment: You won't get "De Proost" in the first string with that. You will have to reconcatenate them.

Comment: @ZouZou You can append a string buffer with rest of the elements in the array.

Comment: Yes but this is very overkill for such a simple task. 2 lines are enough using `substring` and `lastIndexOf`.

Comment: Agreed.. str.lastIndexOf(" "); is better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something like:

```
public static String[] extract(final String string){
    assert string != null;
    final int i = string.lastIndexOf(' ');
    if(i == -1)
        return new String[]{string};
    final String first = string.substring(0, i);
    final String last = string.substring(i+1);
    return new String[]{first, last};
}
```

Usage:

```
final String[] parts = extract("De Proost Wim");
```

Value at each index:

`0: "De Proost"`

`1: "Wim"`